# WordPress Update Killed Site

Tags: wordpress

Help! I updated my website's WordPress version (after like, 2-3 years of never doing so), and my site basically died. There's just a bunch of white on the site everywhere I go, with only like 5% of the actual site remaining.

Upon doing some Google searching, many results from two years ago stated that WP discontinued jQuery support, which killed many sites. I tried to install and activate the "Enable jQuery Migrate Helper" plugin as some jQuery errors were logged in the Developer Console, but that didn't help at all.

Does anyone know what I should do? I'm completely at a loss here!

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
jquery.tools.min.js?ver=6.0.2:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'msie')
    at jquery.tools.min.js?ver=6.0.2:13:204
    at jquery.tools.min.js?ver=6.0.2:13:2814
VM722:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at t.activateScript (rocket-loader.min.js:1:11855)
    at rocket-loader.min.js:1:11052
    at t.run (rocket-loader.min.js:1:11259)
    at rocket-loader.min.js:1:11156
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (rocket-loader.min.js:1:670)
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).overlay is not a function TypeError: jQuery(...).overlay is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (.../wp-content/plugins/wpcomic/assets/jquery.overlay.js?ver=6.0.2:2:22)
    at e (.../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30038)
    at t (.../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30340) undefined
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).overlay is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.overlay.js?ver=6.0.2:2:22)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30038)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30340)
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-hover-bg^=#]
    at se.error (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:13639)
    at se.tokenize (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:21650)
    at se.compile (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:21753)
    at se.select (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:22998)
    at se (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:7116)
    at se.matchesSelector (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:13211)
    at S.filter (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:24737)
    at j (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:24623)
    at s.fn.init.is (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:25232)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (init.js?ver=7.0.7:201:12)
```

Comment: _"many results from two years ago stated that WP discontinued jQuery support"_ Not true

Comment: Keep all the plugins & themes updated, and do all the updates in the staging website first since you have not updated things for the last 2-3 years. so first test all the things on staging the do on the live website. You also need to change if your theme author released any update recently or not and if it's comparable with the latest or last 2-3 versions of wordpress or not. Same with plugins you should check the compatibility and last update from the plugins you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to save my site by downloading and running a plugin called "WP Downgrade" to 5.4.11, which restored former jQuery support. Crisis averted!